# I'm trying to make a canvas on my page but it isn't working

Tags: html, canvas

This is my code:
I don't think the `<head>` `<html>` and `<body>` parts were relevant to my problem. The `<head>` just contained a link to a CSS file.
I was trying to put a canvas into my page but for some reason nothing shows up. Can someone look at my code and see if something is making it not work?

```
  <div id="title">
    <h1 class="main">Options</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="field">
    <p>
    <div id="rad">
      <input type="radio" name="bookmarks" value="ab" checked="checked"> All bookmarks<br>
      <input type="radio" name="bookmarks" value="ao"> One folder<br>
    </div>
    <input id="input" type="text" value="Bookmark folder name">

    <br>

    <button onClick="setname(null);" id="sub">Submit</button>
    </p>
  </div>
  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="500">
  Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
  </canvas>

  <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(9,9,9,9);
  </script>
```

Screenshot:
[imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNtlK.jpg)

Comment: You should *not* wrap `div` within `p` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script code is executing before the canvas has been fully loaded.

Use `window.onload` to wait for the canvas to load:

```
<script>
    window.onload=(function(){
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.fillRect(9,9,9,9);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about that :P